# How to change frame to div and load content into div

Tags: php, html, iframe

Is there any way to convert an iframe with all attributes it contains into a div or php.

```
<iframe src='left_nav.php' name='left_nav' class="daemon" scrolling="auto" frameborder='0' height='100%' width="100%"></iframe>
```

If I use the php include function to call the `left_nav.php` file:

```
<?php include left_nav.php; ?>
```

How to load content which was loading in the frame into the div.

In **main.title** file (other file)

```
function toencounter(rawdata) {


document.getElementById('EncounterHistory').selectedIndex=0;
if(rawdata=='') {
    return false;
} else if (rawdata=='New Encounter') {
    top.window.parent.left_nav.loadFrame2('nen1','RBot','forms/newpatient/new.php? autoloaded=1&calenc=')
    return true;
} else if (rawdata=='Past Encounter List') {
    top.window.parent.left_nav.loadFrame2('pel1','RBot','patient_file/history/encounters.php')
    return true;
}
var parts = rawdata.split("~");
var enc = parts[0];
var datestr = parts[1];
var f = top.window.parent.left_nav.document.forms[0];
frame = 'RBot';
if (!f.cb_bot.checked) {
    frame = 'RTop';
}

parent.left_nav.setEncounter(datestr, enc, frame);
top.frames[frame].location.href  = '../patient_file/encounter/encounter_top.php?set_encounter=' +  enc;
}
```

In **left_nav** file

```
setEncounter(edate, eid, frname) {
if (eid == active_encounter) return;
if (!eid) edate = '<?php xl('None','e'); ?>';
var str = '<b>' + edate + '</b>';
setDivContent('current_encounter', str);
active_encounter = eid;
encounter_locked=isEncounterLocked(active_encounter);
reloadEncounter(frname);
syncRadios();
var encounter_block = $(parent.Title.document.getElementById('current_encounter_block'));
var encounter = $(parent.Title.document.getElementById('current_encounter'));
var estr = '<a href=\'javascript:;\' onclick="parent.left_nav.loadCurrentEncounterFromTitle()">  <b>' + edate + ' (' + eid + ')</b></a>';
encounter.html( estr );
encounter_block.show();
}

function loadCurrentEncounterFromTitle() {
  top.restoreSession();
  top.frames[ parent.left_nav.getEncounterTargetFrame('enc')   ].location='../patient_file/encounter/encounter_top.php';
}
```

This is a JS script to **loadFrame2**

```
function loadFrame2(fname, frame, url) {
var usage = fname.substring(3);
if (active_pid == 0 && usage > '0') {
alert('<?php xl('You must first select or add a visitor.','e') ?>');
return false;
}
if (active_encounter == 0 && usage > '1') {
alert('<?php xl('You must first select or create an encounter.','e') ?>');
return false;
}
if (encounter_locked && usage > '1') {
alert('<?php echo xls('This encounter is locked. No new forms can be added.') ?>');
return false;
}
var f = document.forms[0];
top.restoreSession();
var i = url.indexOf('{PID}');
if (i >= 0) url = url.substring(0,i) + active_pid + url.substring(i+5);
if(f.sel_frame)
{
  var fi = f.sel_frame.selectedIndex;
  if (fi == 1) frame = 'RTop'; else if (fi == 2) frame = 'RBot';
 }
if (!f.cb_bot.checked) frame = 'RTop';
top.frames[frame].location = '<?php echo "$web_root/interface/" ?>' + url;
if (frame == 'RTop') topName = fname;
return false;
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of adding a `name` attribute? The only (modern) purpose it serves is to allow you to target the frame with a link, which you couldn't do if there wasn't a frame there any more.

Comment: You are right Quentin i too require to attain this purpose. Thanks for this advice.

Comment: So, this code is part of an `iframe` too and you changed the source of another `iframe`? Do you need to remove just the left_nav iframe or the other one too?

Comment: I only want to remove left_nav iframe, left_nav.php is a file in which function/method setEncounter is created..

Comment: Updated the answer again. You'll have to do some thinking, but you should get it done with this one.

Comment: I tried it, its only loading left_nav file, but not loading the setEncounter content on the page and showing the error where it should load the content actually.

Comment: Yet you have done a lot and given me a direction as to what i should try atleast..

Comment: Are you sure, that you are addressing the correct path for the file you are loading? Not found could actually be a 404 error.

Comment: Yes i am giving the right path. Should i update js script to help you understand further?

Comment: From the look of it, it' a little more complicated than I thought at the beginning. You would actually have to change all the lines, where you change the `top.frames[...].location` property of the `left_nav` iframe.

Comment: Patrick can you enlighten by an example, this is where i am getting stuck earlier i was using iframe so getting throught url in js script was getting much easier but removing frame and using php instead and then changing `what in line` where top.frames property of the left_nav is turning me mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to load content of an other file (`left_nav.php`) into a `div` rather than into an `iframe`, you can use multiple ways to do that.

**1) JS:**

Create a `div` container which will hold your content:

```
<div id="left_nav"></div>
```

Now, you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to load the content easily:

```
onClick="loadContent('path/to/file/left_nav.php')"
```

This would be your `loadContent` function:

```
function loadContent(path){
  $("#left_nav").load(path);
}
```

**2) PHP:**

You could also use PHP (pass a parameter to the URL you are currently on `yourfile.php?m=left_nav`). Then you can include the file, with a controller (MVC principle -> if you want to learn more about it):

```
<?php
  if($_GET["m"] == "left_nav")
    include("left_nav.php");
?>
```

**EDIT:**

It seems like you need a little mix of both. Instead of your `iframe` you need to insert a `div` and load the content at the same time:

```
<div id="left_nav"><?php include("left_nav.php"); ?></div>
```

This should be equivalent to creating the `iframe`. Now, when you change the `src` of the `iframe` in your JS scripts, instead of using this line:

```
top.window.parent.left_nav.loadFrame2('pel1','RBot','patient_file/history/encounters.php');
```

try changing the content of the `div` as I stated previously at **1)**, but you should only need the loadContent function.

Comment: Attribute name not allowed on div tag

Comment: Yeah, I know, but since you asked about it...  What did you mean by setting a name attribute in PHP then?

Comment: I want to target a div like a frame, which is being targeted by functions or variables in the other file, like this like is targeting a frame onClick=" return top.window.parent.left_nav.loadFrame2('new0','RTop','new/new.php'

Comment: So by clicking on an element, you want to load new content into a `div` instead of an `iframe`?

Comment: Yes i was using a javascript from which this link was targeting frame in the other file.

Comment: And yes this is what i need to do, i want to load a new content into a div instead of an iframe.

Comment: I updated the answer. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is doing some changes but include('') is not working now.

Comment: So you went for the PHP way? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Could you upload the code somewhere, so that I can have a look at it? It seems a little odd, since the error warning should not come from changes I posted.

Comment: Your approach is very much i require, I updated my question, please check and guide me what i need to do?

Comment: Patrick i am accepting your answer as this is contributing some help to me to think in some right direction. and thanks for your support.

Comment: Thank you and you're welcome. I've just not the insight into what the scripts are doing, as well as there are still some functions missing (getEncounterTargetFrame).

Comment: Patrick i have re-posted this question on the page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151012/remove-frames-and-loading-content-into-the-div/26151309?noredirect=1#comment40994824_26151309 with missing functions (getEncounterTargetFrame), if you can, please look into the question and help me sort out this problem because i guess you probably understand my question, and well you are not forced to reply if you dont want to. Thanks.