# Remove frames and loading content into the div

Tags: javascript, php, html, frames

Is there anyway i can unload a page that has been loaded inside an iframe? it likely removing the
windows and loading content from other pages into the `div`?

I am using iframe on my main screen to call a file `left_nav.php`

```
<iframe src='left_nav.php' name='left_nav' class="daemon" scrolling="auto" frameborder='0' height='100%' width="100%"></iframe>
```

In `left_nav` functions and methods to load content from other pages like `main_title.php`

Function created in `left_nav.php` file below

```
setEncounter(edate, eid, frname) {
  if (eid == active_encounter) return;
  if (!eid) edate = '<?php xl('None','e'); ?>';
  var str = '<b>' + edate + '</b>';
  setDivContent('current_encounter', str);
  active_encounter = eid;
  encounter_locked=isEncounterLocked(active_encounter);
  reloadEncounter(frname);
  syncRadios();
  var encounter_block = $(parent.Title.document.getElementById('current_encounter_block'));
  var encounter = $(parent.Title.document.getElementById('current_encounter'));
  var estr = '<a href=\'javascript:;\' onclick="parent.left_nav.loadCurrentEncounterFromTitle()">       <b>' + edate + ' (' + eid + ')</b></a>';
  encounter.html( estr );
  encounter_block.show();
}


function loadCurrentEncounterFromTitle() {
  top.restoreSession();
  top.frames[ parent.left_nav.getEncounterTargetFrame('enc')     ].location='../patient_file/encounter/encounter_top.php';
}


function getEncounterTargetFrame( name ) {
  var bias = <?php echo $primary_docs[ 'enc'  ][ 1 ]?>;
  var f = document.forms[0];
  var r = 'RTop';
  if (f.cb_top.checked) {
    if ( bias == 2 ) {
        r = 'RTop';

    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

This is a js script in `left_nav` to load loadFrame2

```
function loadFrame2(fname, frame, url) {
  var usage = fname.substring(3);
  if (active_pid == 0 && usage > '0') {
    alert('<?php xl('You must first select or add a visitor.','e') ?>');
    return false;
  }
  if (active_encounter == 0 && usage > '1') {
    alert('<?php xl('You must first select or create an encounter.','e') ?>');
    return false;
  }
  if (encounter_locked && usage > '1') {
    alert('<?php echo xls('This encounter is locked. No new forms can be added.') ?>');
    return false;
  }
  var f = document.forms[0];
  top.restoreSession();
  var i = url.indexOf('{PID}');
  if (i >= 0) url = url.substring(0,i) + active_pid + url.substring(i+5);
  if(f.sel_frame) {
    var fi = f.sel_frame.selectedIndex;
    if (fi == 1) frame = 'RTop'; else if (fi == 2) frame = 'RBot';
  }
  if (!f.cb_bot.checked) frame = 'RTop';
  top.frames[frame].location = '<?php echo "$web_root/interface/" ?>' + url;
  if (frame == 'RTop') topName = fname;
  return false;
}
```

Funtions created in `main_title.php` file.

```
function toencounter(rawdata) {
  document.getElementById('EncounterHistory').selectedIndex=0;
  if(rawdata=='') {
    return false;
  } else if (rawdata=='New Encounter') {
    top.window.parent.left_nav.loadFrame2('nen1','RBot','forms/newpatient/new.php?   autoloaded=1&calenc=')
    return true;
  } else if (rawdata=='Past Encounter List') {
    top.window.parent.left_nav.loadFrame2('pel1','RBot','patient_file/history/encounters.php')
    return true;
  }
  var parts = rawdata.split("~");
  var enc = parts[0];
  var datestr = parts[1];
  var f = top.window.parent.left_nav.document.forms[0];
  frame = 'RBot';
  if (!f.cb_bot.checked) {
    frame = 'RTop';
  }

  parent.left_nav.setEncounter(datestr, enc, frame);
  top.frames[frame].location.href  = '../patient_file/encounter/encounter_top.php?set_encounter=' +     enc;
}
```

Comment: You explained the problem but can you clarify what the current behavior is and how it differs from desired results?

Comment: When i use php include to call a left_nav file like was being used with `src` in iframe. It simply does not load the content in other frames like on the very top of the page encounter visit does not work and load which even turn off many pages functionality based on encounter visit.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of code where the new iframe source is set, you're using the href attribute instead of the src.  Since iframe does not have an href attribute, that would explain the lack of results.

```
top.frames[frame].src  = '../patient_file/encounter/encounter_top.php?set_encounter=' +     enc;
```

Try changing to that and see if it works.

Comment: But i want to remove iframe and use div instead to call and load the content by using `php include` main reason to remove frame is simply because left_nav file is where menu navigatigation was created on the left side and i want to change the left to make the menu horizontal, which is not quite good with iframe.

Comment: Then why the iframe to begin with?

Comment: As i mentioned that earlier a frame on the left side was used for menus and keeping in mind the encounter functionality dependent on the menu and frame was created but now i want to make the menu left to top, only thats the reason of removing the frames